# Broadcast Receiver suggestion

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

My current project method only works to connect sync with my remote db when mobile data is turned on. How do I implement the same this time by using wifi? What code will I add to make it work on Wifi and Mobile data.

Here is my broadcast receiver.

```
public class NetworkMonitor extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (checkNetworkConnection(context))
        {
            final DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(context);
            final SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

           Cursor cursor = dbHelper.readFromLocalDatabase(database);

            while (cursor.moveToNext())
            {
                int sync_status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.SYNC_STATUS));
                if (sync_status == DBContract.SYNC_STATUS_FAILED)
                {
                    final String Name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.NAME));
                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, DBContract.SERVER_URL,
                            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                    try {
                                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                        String Response = jsonObject.getString("response");
                                        if (Response.equals("OK"))
                                        {
                                            dbHelper.updateLocalDatabase(Name,DBContract.SYNC_STATUS_OK,database);
                                            context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(DBContract.UI_UPDATE_BROADCAST));
                                        }

                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        }
                    })
                    {
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                            params.put("name",Name);
                            return params;
                        }
                    }
                            ;
                    MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQue(stringRequest);

                }
            }

        }
    }
`

    public boolean checkNetworkConnection(Context context)
    {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (networkInfo!= null && networkInfo.isConnected());
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is when mobile data is turned off and a record is inserted it is saved to local sqlite. And when i turn on mobile data it automatically uploads that record to the remote mysql db. But when I do the same on WiFi. When i turn it off and turn it on it does not automatically send the record to the remote mysql db.

Answer (score 0):

ConnectivityManager will basically give the network connection status regardless mobile data or wifi.So your code should work for both conditions.

Comment: But when I try to run it, On Android Studio emulator, When mobile data is turned off and I inserted a record and when I turn on mobile data it automatically sync and save data to remote db. But when I do that using Wifi it only saves data to remote db when wifi is turned on. But when i turn wifi off and add data and turn it on , it does not sync. unline in mobile data.

PS: Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Can you please try it on real device?

Comment: I tried doing the mobile data thing in emulator and it works fine. And I tried doing the WiFi thing in a real device and that is where the sync does not happen. Unfortunately, I cant try using mobile data on my real device because my database is not yet online and is only remote that can be accessed only on my LAN network.